# Blender file from Blender 2.49 to 2.79 when rendering changes default screen layout

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, compositing-nodes, versions

I used Boujou and a script in Blender 2.49 then opened the file in 2.79. Now when I render, I get redirected to a different screen layout:

[image]

And my composite that adds the video background doesn't load as well in this view unless I re-open the Composite Node editor.

Is there a way to do something similar to reset the settings to a project in Blender 2.79?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a wild step in the dark since I haven't used 2.49 in quite a while. But there's two things you can try.

- Make a new file and append the data you need from the other file with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>. That way you should be able to isolate pretty well what is broken and what isn't.
- You can disable 'Load UI' when loading the old file.

Comment: #1 Is what should have been done in the first place. Files jumping between such different versions of a software is never a good thing

Comment: I don't like jumping either, but it's the only thing that works with Boujou at the moment.